# How to make a scatter plot with varying scatter size and color corresponding to a range of values from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a Dataframe

```
df = 
Magnitude,Lon,Lat,Depth
3.5  33.3   76.2    22
3.5  33.1   75.9    34
2.5  30.5   79.6    25
5.5  30.4   79.5    40
5.1  32     78.8    58
4.5  31.5   74      NaN
2.1  33.9   74.7    64
5.1  30.8   79.1    33
1.1  32.6   78.2    78
NaN  33.3   76      36
5.2  32.7   79.5    36
NaN  33.6   78.6    NaN
```

I wanted to make a scatter plot with Lon in X-Axis Lat in Y-axis and scatter points with different size according to the range of values in Magnitude ;

```
size =1 : Magnitude<2 ,  size =1.5 : 2<Magnitude<3,  size =2 : 3<Magnitude<4,  size =2.5 : Magnitude>4.
```

and with different colour according to the range of values in Depth ;

```
 color =red : Depth<30 ,  color =blue : 30<Depth<40,  color =black : 40<Depth<60,   color =yellow : Depth>60
```

I am thinking to solve this problem by defining a dictionary for the size and color. ( Just giving the idea ; need the correct syntax)

**More like**

```
def magnitude_size(df.Magnitude):
    if df.Magnitude < 2 :
        return 1
    if df.Magnitude > 2 and df.Magnitude < 3 :
        return 1.5
    if df.Magnitude > 3 and df.Magnitude < 4 :
        return 2
    if df.Magnitude > 4  :
        return 2.5


def depth_color(df.Depth):
    if df.Depth < 30 :
        return 'red'
    if df.Depth > 30 and df.Depth < 40 :
        return 'blue'
    if df.Depth > 40 and df.Depth < 60 :
        return 'black'
    if df.Depth > 60  :
        return 'yellow'


di = {
    'size': magnitude_size(df.Magnitude),
    'color' : depth_color(df.Depth)
}

plt.scatter(df.Lon,df.Lat,c=di['color'],s=di['size'])

plt.show()
```

***If there any NaN values in Magnitude give a different symbol for the scatter point (*) and If there any NaN values in Depth give a different color (green)***

**NEED HELP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) to create a couple of helper columns in `df` based on your `color` and `size` mappings.  This should make it easier to pass these arguments to [`pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

*N.B. It's worth noting that the values you've chosen for size may not distinguish the markers very well in the plot - it'd be worth experimenting with different sizes until you get the desired results*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['color'] = pd.cut(df['Depth'], bins=[-np.inf, 30, 40, 60, np.inf], labels=['red', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow'])
df['size'] = pd.cut(df['Magnitude'], bins=[-np.inf, 2, 3, 4, np.inf], labels=[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5])

plt.scatter(df['Lon'], df['Lat'], c=df['color'], s=df['size'])
```

[image]

---

#### Update

It's not what I would recommend, but if you insist on using `dict` and `functions` then use:

```
def magnitude_size(magnitude):
    if magnitude < 2 :
        return 1
    if magnitude >= 2 and magnitude < 3 :
        return 1.5
    if magnitude >= 3 and magnitude < 4 :
        return 2
    if magnitude >= 4  :
        return 2.5


def depth_color(depth):
    if depth < 30 :
        return 'red'
    if depth >= 30 and depth < 40 :
        return 'blue'
    if depth >= 40 and depth < 60 :
        return 'black'
    if depth >= 60  :
        return 'yellow'
    if np.isnan(depth):
        return 'green'

di = {
    'size': df.Magnitude.apply(magnitude_size),
    'color' : df.Depth.apply(depth_color)
}

plt.scatter(df.Lon,df.Lat,c=di['color'],s=di['size'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable feedback!
Is it possible to solve this problem by defining a dictionary? (added more to question)

Comment: @VGB added syntax for your preferred approach

Comment: Thank you so much @chris,
But one problem I am facing with your first method is that;
there are some NaN values for Depth in my original data set.
I tried to fill that NaN values with:

df.color = df.color.cat.add_categories('green')
df.color.fillna('green')

.But still giving the error

Comment: you should deal with `NaN` values before mapping to a color, trying `fillna` with a default value like `-1` for example and map that to `green`. Difficult to show since your sample data does not contain `NaN`s.  Alternatively, add another line to your `depth_color` function to handle `NaN` values

Comment: Thank you @ Chris!!